# Trouble with UriMapper

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I got the navigation up and running in my application but I wanted to hide the real path to views so I wrote this UriMapper:

```
<Application
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="MyApplication.App" 
    xmlns:navcore="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation">
 <Application.Resources>
  <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <navcore:UriMapper x:Key="uriMapper">
            <navcore:UriMapping Uri="{}{page}" MappedUri="/Views/{page}.xaml" />
        </navcore:UriMapper>
 </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is my navigation button click event code:

```
    private void NavigateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        string uri = btn.Tag.ToString();

        this.ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

And here is XAML of a button:

```
<Button Content="Home" Click="NavigateButton_Click" Tag="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="30" />
```

However, when I click on a button, I am getting this error:

```
Content for the URI cannot be loaded. The URI may be invalid.
```

At this line:

```
this.ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

More XAML files... MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Class="MyApplication.MainPage">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/bg.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF252525" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.7" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Margin="0,100,0,0" StrokeThickness="0" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="350" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="NavigationCanvas" Margin="0,50,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="600">
            <toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme Height="30" Canvas.Left="188" Canvas.Top="11" Width="100" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Button Content="Home" Click="NavigateButton_Click" Tag="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="30" />
            </toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
                        <!-- etc more buttons -->
        </Canvas>

        <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="15,115,15,0" Height="320" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Home">            
        </navigation:Frame>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Home.xaml:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="MyApplication.Views.Home" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
    Title="Home">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="570" Height="320" >
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White">
            Home.
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>

</navigation:Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This outlines the issues, give [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/MisterGoodcat/archive/2009/07/14/breaking-changes-in-silverlights-navigation-framework.aspx) a try...

Comment: That's what UriMapper is supposed to take care of - see the first code snippets, URIs are explicit there.

Comment: Your Home is in the Views folder?

Comment: Yes. That's how I wrote this navigation.

Comment: Go forward few minutes he does the same thing as me in that video.

Comment: Everything I am looking at has the whack in front...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(VS.95).aspx, edited above to try something

Comment: By Tim himself: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/22/silverlight-navigation-framework-and-uri-routing.aspx Second code snippet.

Comment: Yes my Home.xaml is in the Views folder. And your suggested solution doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the output of your ToString?

Comment: The output of ToString() is "Home".

Comment: If you change the point of navigation to be the explicit path, just to make sure that works...all is peachy? ie../Views/Home.xaml

Comment: I have added MainPage.xaml and Home.xaml.

Comment: Ok, so what is the value of the URI once it has been called? Pull it out of the Navigate and see what it is, since the FW is going to in theory use the mapping at that point in time

Comment: The value is "Home" after clicking, it's like the UriMapper doesn't work at all.

Comment: Move the urimapper XAML to your frame...like this...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.urimapper(VS.95).aspx see if it works...something with it as application resource

Comment: @Richard, check my post, I edited it, give that a try, couple of items to note there which is why it is not working